# CSS : Square with min/max width and wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to get two divs which are perfect squares that scale depending the width of the device.
Those squares have a min and a max width (obviously height too, since they are squares).
At first they are one next to the other, once they wrapped, I would like that the squares are 80vw.

I have a solution that's almost perfect, but my squares aren't shrinking till wrap treshold.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.25rem;
  background-color: #9e9ef8;
}

.square {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 400px;
  height: 80vw;
  flex: 0 1 80vw;
  background-color:#cacaca;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

I do think that it's because of the 80vw, but I don't get how I could do it without media queries.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not a perfect square even if you have calculated that way, however, an answer to your request is this:

```
.square {
width: 80vw;
height: 80vw;
background-color:#cacaca;
```

}
and like this, you don't need media queries.

Comment: It's a square because of `flex: 0 1 80vw;` that's acting like `width: 80vw;`
In your solution the min and max width / height aren't specified and if I just had it, I have the same result. 
My squares aren't shrinking while they are one next to the other.